Event for stock update in magento
I just wanted to know that 'when the product stock will update'?

After the product is added to cart?
After checkout?
After order shipped or when?

Because, I want to run a custom 'product_sync_indexer' whenever the product stock is updated.
So,please guide me which event/events should I use to fulfill above requirement?
Note: I am looking for a solution that works on MSI also.
Thank you!

Magento’s inventory flow is designed to handle stock updates at different stages of the sales process. Here's an overview of how and when product stock gets updated:
1. Product Added to Cart:

No Stock Update: When a customer adds a product to their cart, Magento does not reduce the stock at this point. This is because multiple customers can add the same product to their carts, but inventory isn't reserved until a purchase is confirmed.

2. Checkout (Order Placed):

Stock Reservation or Deduction (depending on setup):

When the order is placed, Magento can handle stock updates in two different ways depending on the stock management configuration:

With Inventory Management (MSI - Multi-Source Inventory): Stock is reserved rather than immediately deducted. This ensures stock is locked for that customer, but is not officially removed until the order is processed further.
Without MSI: Magento reduces the stock as soon as the order is placed. This means the stock is deducted from the available quantity immediately.





3. Order Processing:

No Stock Update: During order processing, like invoicing or payment confirmation, the stock remains as either reserved or deducted, depending on your setup.

4. Order Shipped:

Stock Deduction (if MSI): If you're using MSI and stock was reserved at checkout, the stock is finally deducted when the order is shipped. This means the actual stock quantity reduces only when the product is shipped out to the customer.

5. Order Canceled/Refunded:

Stock Restored: If an order is canceled or refunded, Magento will restore the stock that was reserved or deducted, making the product available again for sale.

In summary:

Adding to Cart: No stock change.
Checkout: Stock is reserved or deducted based on the setup.
Order Shipped: Final stock deduction happens if using MSI.
Cancellation/Refund: Stock is restored.


Thank you for the answer.
Will it work if I use "sales_order_save_after" event and inside the observer I check for "$order->getState() == 'complete' || $order->getState() == 'closed')" if yes then I will run my custom 'product_sync_indexer'
Also I will use another event called 'sales_order_place_after'.
